# why typeid returns that int and const int are same types

Tags: c++, typeid

```
if(typeid(int) == typeid(const int))
       cout << "Same types"<< endl;
```

**PROGRAM OUTPUT:**

> Same types

am I missing something?
these are not same types lol.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They aren't the same type, but the `typeid` operator strips `const` and `volatile`.

From section 5.2.8 `[expr.typeid]`:

> The top-level *cv-qualifiers* of the glvalue expression or the *type-id* that is the operand of `typeid` are always ignored.

Answer (score 7):

You probably want this instead:

```
#include <type_traits>

if (std::is_same<int, const int>::value)
    std::cout << "same types\n";
else
    std::cout << "different types\n";
```