# Why type deduced for T is const int in void func(T const &t)

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

I am reading about type deduction in templates, and here is a question that bothers me

```
template<typename T>
void funt(T const &t);
int x = 10;
func(x);
```

`T` will be deduced to be `const int`, and the type of `t` will be `int const &`
I understand the reasons for why `t` has to be `int const &`, so that `x`passed to the function would remain the same, because function accepts `const T&`.
But I don't see the reason why `T` has to be also `const`. Seems to me that deducing `T` to be `int` would not break anything within this piece of code?
Like in another example:

```
template<typename T>
void funt(T const &t);
int const x = 10;
func(x);
```

Here `T` is deduced to just `int`, and `const` of `x` is omitted

Or am I missing something here?

Comment: "Deduce" is what Sherlock Holmes does. "Deduct" is what your boss does with your salary when she catches you browsing the internet at work. "Deduct" is also what a brake does to the speed of a bus.

Comment: What gives you the idea that `T` is deduced as `const int`?! [Counter-example](http://ideone.com/eWnyQQ)

Comment: If `T` were deduced as `const int`, it would imply that you have `void funt(const const int & t)`. The correct type for `T` is clearly `int` here. Replace `T` with `int` and see for yourself that the deduction is correct. You get `void funt(int const &t);`

Comment: Can't duplicate. http://ideone.com/aRnclc.

Comment: @Kerrek My inattentiveness made me think that way. I checked the book now, and i see where i got it wrong.  Which word by the way can i apply here? Deduction, right?

Comment: @Vaskaelgato: Well, "deduction" is the noun for both verbs "deduce" (= conclude) and "deduct" (= take away from)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type deduction rules are not very straightforward. But as a general rule of thumb, there are 3 main type-deduction cases:

1. `f(/*const volatile*/ T& arg)` - In this instance, the compiler performs something similar to "pattern matching" on the argument to deduce the type `T`. In your second case, it perfectly matches the type of your argument, i.e. `int const`, with `T const`, hence `T` is deduced as `int`. In case the argument lacks CV-qualifiers, like in your first example, then the compiler does not consider them in the pattern matching. So, when you pass e.g. an `int x` to `f(const T& param)`, then `const` is being discarded during the pattern matching and `T` is deduced as `int`, hence `f` being instantiated to `f(const int&)`.
2. `f(/*const volatile*/ T arg)` - The `cv`-ness (const/volatile) and the references-ness of the argument is ignored. So if you have something like `const int& x = otherx;` and pass `x` to `template<class T> void f(T param)`, then `T` is deduced as `int`.
3. `f(T&& arg)` - `T` is deduced as either a lvalue reference (like `int&`) or a rvalue (like `int`), depending whether `arg` is a lvalue or a rvalue, respectively. This case is a bit more complicated, and I advise to read more about forwarding references and reference collapsing rules to understand what's going on.

Scott Meyers discusses template type deduction in Chapter 1 of [*Effective Modern C++*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033707.do) book in great detail. That chapter is actually free online, see https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/effective-modern-c/9781491908419/ch01.html.

Comment: This is the book i am reading right now, and as i said in a comment to my question i just got it wrong. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Vaskaelgato Think about template type deduction as pattern matching (for the reference case) and everything will make sense.

Comment: I don't want to create the same question that is related to the same topic. I guess there is a mistake in the book. At the very end of the Case1, where they show example when param is a pointer or a pointer to const. The book says that T is const int, and param's type is const int*
But here is the code that shows me that T is int, and param's type is const int* http://ideone.com/7xsJKh

Comment: @Vaskaelgato I think it's an issue with the demangler (I believe the `const` is being dropped from the type by `typeid`). Just try to use `std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;` inside the called function body and you'll see the name of the function as well as the template types. So in your case `T = const char` as you would expect, see it live [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5abca7b0d6d74f51).

Comment: @Vaskaelgato So yes, `typeid(char) == typeid(const char)` for the compiler, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/8888960/3093378. So rely on `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` to find out the actual type.

Comment: Now i see. Thank you a lot again for help.

Comment: @Vaskaelgato BTW, the `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is a macro defined only by gcc and clang, so it is not standard. Visual Studio has something similar, see [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/02c69018-a182-48b3-94d1-250252aa00a7/prettyfunction?forum=vclanguage).